# Warning: Error in writeImpl: Text to be written must be a length-one character vector in RStudio Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio-server

I dont know why i got this error message and how to fix it. Especially because it works for other value boxes.
Would be thankful for help.

```
output$value3 <- renderValueBox({
    if(input$geschlecht=='Female'){
      
      prof.prod=filter(prof.prod, Geschlecht == "Female")
    }else{
      prof.prod=filter(prof.prod, Geschlecht == "Male")
    }
    valueBox(formatC(prof.prod$value, format="d", big.mark=',')
              ,paste(prof.prod$Produktlinie)
              ,icon = icon("menu-hamburger",lib='glyphicon')
              ,color = "yellow")
  })
```

Comment: It looks like `prof.prod` has more than one row. But without a reproducible example, it’s impossible to be sure. And why not write `prof.prod=filter(prof.prod, Geschlecht == input$Geschlecht)` avoiding the need for the `if` statement?

Comment: do you know how i could smaller the size of the value "Produktlinie" so maybe that the text size is smaller or something like that?